# Display a chart using ngx-chart from a rest API

Tags: angular, ngx-charts

I am using **ngx-charts** for my project and I have followed this link but I am not able to make it work for me.

[how to initialize chart with API fetch data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54605869/how-to-initialize-chart-with-api-fetch-data)

this is my data that i consume from my backend:

```
[
 {
  "date": "09-01-2019",
  "Close": 34.58000183105469
 },
 {
  "date": "08-01-2019",
  "Close": 34.279998779296875
 },
 {
  "date": "07-01-2019",
  "Close": 33.93000030517578
 },
 {
  "date": "04-01-2019",
  "Close": 33.81999969482422
 },
 {
  "date": "03-01-2019",
  "Close": 33.31999969482422
 },
 {
  "date": "02-01-2019",
  "Close": 33.2400016784668
 }
]
```

this is my method from the service:

```
public prices() {
    return this.http.get<any[]>('http://127.0.0.1:8000/prices/active/acs')
  }
```

this is my component:

```
export class NgxchartsComponent  implements OnInit{

  multi$: any[] = []
  view: any[] = [1700, 600];


  // options
  legend: boolean = true;
  showLabels: boolean = true;
  animations: boolean = true;
  xAxis: boolean = true;
  yAxis: boolean = true;
  showYAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  showXAxisLabel: boolean = true;
  xAxisLabel: string = 'Days';
  yAxisLabel: string = 'Prices';
  timeline: boolean = true;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#E44D25', '#CFC0BB', '#7aa3e5', '#a8385d', '#aae3f5']
  };
  
  constructor(private res: RecursoService) { }

  ngOnInit() {        
    this.res.prices().subscribe(data => {
     this.multi$ = data.map(datum => ({name: datum.date, value: datum.Close}));
  })  
  }
```

And this is the view of the component:

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart
[view]="view" 
[scheme]="colorScheme" 
[legend]="legend" 
[showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" 
[showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel"
[xAxis]="xAxis" 
[yAxis]="yAxis" 
[xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" 
[yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel" 
[timeline]="timeline"
[results]="multi$">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

And there are the errors when i try to execute:

[image: Error from console in google chrome]

I tried this in the html but it didnt work

```
<ngx-charts-line-chart *ngIf="multi$ | async as multiseries" 
[view]="view" 
[scheme]="colorScheme" 
[legend]="legend" 
[showXAxisLabel]="showXAxisLabel" 
[showYAxisLabel]="showYAxisLabel" 
[xAxis]="xAxis" 
[yAxis]="yAxis" 
[xAxisLabel]="xAxisLabel" 
[yAxisLabel]="yAxisLabel"
[timeline]="timeline" 
[results]="multiseries">
</ngx-charts-line-chart>
```

[image: Error using async in html]